# c check two strings for same characters

Tags: c, string, compare

Im just starting to learn C programming and for exercise i found one task. First i have to scan in two strings. Then i have to compare them character by character and if there are any same characters i have to print out the amount of the same characters.
It has to be done with pointers. So lets i have "boat" and "ship" so the program would return 0. But if it were "boat" and "soap" it would return 2.

This is what i've got so far but when i run it it gives me errors. I put the errors in comments.

Thanks in advance for your help.

#include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

int number_of_same_characters(char *, char *);

int main()
{
    char * first[100];
    char * second[100];
    int  result = 0;    

    printf("Enter first string\n");
    gets(*first);

    printf("Enter second string\n");
    gets(*second);

    result = number_of_same_characters(*first, *second);   
    printf("%d\n", result); 
    return 0;
}

int number_of_same_characters(char *p, char *q){ //i get this error here - error:  invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
    int counter = 0;

        for(int j = 0; *p[j] != '\0' || *q[j] != '\0'; ++j){  //i get this error here -  error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)    
            if(strcmp(*p[j], *q[j])){       
                 ++counter;        
           }        
    }   
    return counter;
}

Comment: `char *first[100];` --> `char first[100];` --> `gets(first)` --> `number_of_same_characters(first, second)` --> ... etc.

Comment: [`gets` is evil](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html#index-gets).  Don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined character arrays incorrectly and incorrectly are using operator *.

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N    100

int number_of_same_characters( const char *, const char * );

int main()
{
    char first[N];
    char second[N];
    int  result = 0;    
    size_t n;

    printf( "Enter first string: ");
    fgets( first, N, stdin );

    n = strlen( first );
    if ( first[n - 1] == '\n' ) first[n - 1] = '\0';

    printf( "Enter second string: ");
    fgets( second, N, stdin );

    n = strlen( second );
    if ( second[n - 1] == '\n' ) second[n - 1] = '\0';

    result = number_of_same_characters( first, second );   

    printf( "%d\n", result );

    return 0;
}

int number_of_same_characters( const char *p, const char *q )
{
    int counter = 0;
    int i;

    for( i = 0; p[i] != '\0' && q[i] != '\0'; ++i )
    {
        if ( p[i] == q[i] ) ++counter;        
    }

    return counter;
}
```

If to enter boat and soap then the output will be

```
2
```

Comment: @niko85 I had a typo. There shall be for( i = 0; p[i] != '\0' && q[i] != '\0'; ++i )

Answer (score 4):

Mainly you've got a lot of extra `*`'s littering the program. The variable declarations should be:

```
char first[100];
char second[100];
```

The input calls should be<sup>†</sup>:

```
gets(first);
gets(second);
```

The method call should be:

```
result = number_of_same_characters(first, second);
```

And finally there shouldn't be any dereferences in the for loop.

```
for(int j = 0; p[j] != '\0' || q[j] != '\0'; ++j){     
    if(strcmp(p[j], q[j])){       
       ++counter;        
    }        
}
```

That'll get you closer, though there are still a couple of problems. As a hint, the `||` operator is suspect, and you don't need to use `strcmp`.

<sub><sup>†</sup> It's worth pointing out that `gets()` is a dangerous function that can lead to buffer overflows. It's okay to use when you're just starting out, but don't let it become a habit, and don't ever use it in production code!</sub>